# React JSX expressions must have a parent element error when adding a second <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When I try to add another  react returns the error `JSX Expressions must have one parent element`. I don't see why this is as it has a parent element.

```
  return (
<div className="loginButton">
    <header className="loginButton">
        <button className='discordLogin' id='login'
            href="link-here"></button>
    </header>
</div>
<div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
        <img key={speed} src={logo} style={animationStyle} className="App-logo-circle" id='spinnerLogo'
            alt="Spinning logo" />
        <p>Hello, and welcome to the begining of the Swiss Plus Website. <strong>We hope you enjoy your stay</strong>
        </p>
        <button className='App-button' id='fastLogoButton' onClick={faster}>Increase Spin Speed!</button>
        <button className='App-button' id='slowLogoButton' onClick={slower}>Decrease Spin Speed!</button>
    </header>
</div>
  );
```

PS. The error happens at the ) of the return.

Comment: You have two <div>'s.  Wrap them in a <Fragment>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this error because you are returning two elements simultaneously.
Both your divs need to be wrap in a parent element.

You could use **React.Fragment** to do this. As mentioned in the docs(https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactfragment)

> The React.Fragment component lets you return multiple elements in a render() 
>   method without creating an additional DOM element

```
return(
<React.Fragment>
 <div className="loginButton">
    <header className="loginButton">
        <button className='discordLogin' id='login'
            href="link-here"></button>
    </header>
 </div>
 <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
        <img key={speed} src={logo} style={animationStyle} className="App-logo-circle" 
          id='spinnerLogo'
          alt="Spinning logo" 
        />
        <p>Hello, and welcome to the begining of the Swiss Plus Website. <strong>We hope 
          you enjoy your stay</strong>
        </p>
        <button className='App-button' id='fastLogoButton' onClick={faster}>
          Increase Spin Speed!
        </button>
        <button className='App-button' id='slowLogoButton' onClick={slower}>
          Decrease SpinSpeed!
        </button>
    </header>
  </div>
</React.Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

React components require you to return only one element. A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

```
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

Usually these elements are wrapped for example inside a div. In most cases the wrapper div is “irrelevant” and is only added because React components require you to return only one element. [Read more on fragment](https://dev.to/tumee/react-fragments-what-why-how-2kh1) and [check official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).